# Gruntfile add javascript files

Tags: javascript, compass-sass, livereload, bootstrap-sass, gruntfile

I created a bootstrap-compass project with the following yeoman generator:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-bootstrap-compass

You can see the file structure in the link.

How do I add the javascripts to this gruntfile correctly?

The gruntfile.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        config: {
            app: 'app'
        },

        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                livereload: 35729,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= config.app %>/public'
                    ]
                }
            },
        },
        watch: {
            options: {
                livereload: true,
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= config.app %>/public/{,*/}*.html',
                    '<%= config.app %>/public/css/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= config.app %>/public/images/{,*/}*'
                ]
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['**/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:dev']
            },
        },
        compass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    sassDir: ['app/src/stylesheets'],
                    cssDir: ['app/public/css'],
                    environment: 'development'
                }
            },
            prod: {
                options: {
                    sassDir: ['app/src/stylesheets'],
                    cssDir: ['app/public/css'],
                    environment: 'production'
                }
            },
        }
    });

    // Load the plugin
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect:livereload', 'compass:dev', 'watch']);
    // prod build
    grunt.registerTask('prod', ['compass:prod']);

};
```

**EDIT:**

Solution:

I just added grunt-contrib-uglify and the following code to my gruntfile.js to compress any js codes in my project:

```
uglify: {
            all: {
                files: {
                  '<%= config.app %>/public/js/bootstrap.min.js': ['<%= config.app %>/src/javascripts/bootstrap.js']
                }
            },
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a very short and interesting video explaining how Grunt works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMKj0BxzVgw. 
But if you can't watch it right now, read this http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks

I hope I have helped.